# Horizontal Line level detection and tracking

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I recorded a video of material flow in slo-mo  ([link here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12a9_Cv6V5sXox0Re3GrILWK3zyer2J9J/view?usp=sharing)) and I want to track the material level inside the cylinder
[image: Material Flow]

I have used color-based thresholding to segment the foreground and the background (as the background is yellow, although I have some videos with a different background).

Firstly, I pick a color in the material column, and then the color threshold starts to detect it. The detection seems to work quite well as you can see in the image below but I am wondering what I could do to improve the detection

[image: Detection]

Furthermore, I also want to add a horizontal line at the material level to track at every frame but I am unsure how to do it. Notice the black region is where the it detected

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

My code snippet is shown below

```
import cv2
import os
from skimage import filters
import numpy as np

def extract_frames(video_path, output_folder):
    # Open the video file
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    
    # Get the frames per second (fps) and frame count
    fps = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
    total_frames = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    
    # Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    # Loop through each frame and save it as an image
    for frame_num in range(total_frames):
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        
        # Break the loop when the video ends
        if not ret:
            break
        
        # Save the frame as an image
        frame_filename = f"{output_folder}/frame_{frame_num:04d}.png"
        cv2.imwrite(frame_filename, frame)
    
    # Release the video capture object
    video_capture.release()

material_masks = []

def preprocess_frame(frame):
    # Convert frame to grayscale
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return gray_frame

def segment_material_region(edges):
    # Implement image segmentation to isolate the material region using simple thresholding
    _, binary_mask = cv2.threshold(edges, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # Adjust the threshold value as needed
    return binary_mask


def color_based_thresholding(frame, lb, ub):
    # Convert frame to HSV color space (Hue, Saturation, Value)
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    # Define the lower and upper bounds of the color range for the material
    lower_bound = np.array(lb)   # Adjust the lower bound to match the material's color
    upper_bound = np.array(ub)  # Adjust the upper bound to match the material's color
    
    # Create a binary mask based on the color range
    binary_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, lower_bound, upper_bound)
    return binary_mask



# Load the video
video_path = 'IMG_4146.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Initialize a list to store the material heights over time
material_heights = []


# get first frame to get roi
_,frame = cap.read()
roi = cv2.selectROI("Image", frame, fromCenter=False, showCrosshair=True)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if roi == (0,0,0,0):
    roi = (0,0,frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0])
frame = frame[int(roi[1]):int(roi[1] + roi[3]), int(roi[0]):int(roi[0] + roi[2])]

# Convert ROI to HSV color space
roi_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Find the pixel with the lowest HSV values
min_hsv = np.min(roi_hsv, axis=(0, 1))
max_hsv = np.max(roi_hsv, axis=(0, 1))
print(min_hsv, max_hsv)
# Set the number of frames to process and the skip interval
num_frames_to_process = 1000
skip_interval = 10
for frame_counter in range(num_frames_to_process):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Skip frames based on the skip interval
    if frame_counter % skip_interval != 0:
        continue
    
    # Preprocess the frame
    processed_frame = preprocess_frame(frame)

    
    # Apply color-based thresholding to obtain a binary mask
    color_mask = color_based_thresholding(frame, min_hsv, max_hsv)
    
    
    # Invert the color mask to highlight the material region in the foreground
    inverted_color_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(color_mask)
 
    # Use the color mask as a mask to extract the foreground (material region) from the frame
    foreground = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=inverted_color_mask)

    # Show the processed frame
    cv2.imshow('Foreground (Material Region)', foreground)  
    if cv2.waitKey(1000) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: physically remove the reflection of the light source. do that by putting the light source to the side, and/or applying a light polarization filter. that's a physical thing. -- take row sums of the segmentation mask. plot the signal. you'll see.